# How to fill a button with image in python gtk

Tags: python, gtk

I have created a gtk button with an image on it. The size of my image is 150x150. I want to create a button of 150x150 and it should be same even while maximizing the window.

```
image = gtk.Image()
image.set_from_file("/home/jeevan/Pictures/msnbus.png")
box1=gtk.VBox()
box2=gtk.HBox()
box1.pack_start(box2)
gobutton=gtk.Button()
gobutton.add(image)
gobutton.set_size_request(150,150)
box2.pack_start(gobutton)
```

[image: button when unmaximized]

[image: button while maximized]

I want mybutton to be of same 150x150 size even when maximized. How is it possible in python gtk?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't want the Gtk.Button to expand so you should do something like this:

```
gobutton.set_hexpand(False)
gobutton.set_halign(Gtk.Align.CENTER)
gobutton.set_vexpand(False)
gobutton.set_valign(Gtk.Align.CENTER)
```

Instead of `Gtk.Align.CENTER` you can of course also use `Gtk.Align.END`, `Gtk.Align.START` or `Gtk.Align.BASELINE`.

**EDIT:**

For Gtk+ 2 (with pygtk) you can pack the Gtk.Button in another Gtk.Box with two Gtk.Alignments

```
image = gtk.Image.new_from_file("filename")
button = gtk.Button()
button.add(image)

inner_box = gtk.VBox()
inner_box.pack_start(gtk.Alignment(), True, True, 0)
inner_box.pack_start(button, False, False, 0)
inner_box.pack_start(gtk.Alignment(), True, True, 0)

outer_box = gtk.HBox()
outer_box.pack_start(gtk.Label("some widget"), True, True, 0)
outer_box.pack_start(inner_box, False, False, 0)
```

Comment: After using your code I get this error:                                                                                                                         AttributeError: 'gtk.Button' object has no attribute 'set_hexpand'

Comment: See the edit in my answer. If you are writing a new program, you should consider switching to gtk+ 3.